# reactjs .env add localhost:3000 to my axios path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react app

I am using axios for api request

I added my base url in .env

when I submitted my form and I checked the network tab

I saw this

```
http://localhost:3000/%22http://localhost:8000/api/%22;get-name
```

instead of this

```
localhost:8000/api/get-name
```

.env

```
REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/";
```

my code

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios";
const Home = () => {

 const getName = () => {

 axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}get-name`, {"name": "John Stone"})
      .then((respons) => {})
      .catch((error) => {})
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("finished...");
      });
  }
  return (
     <div><button onClick={getName}>Get Name</button>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your environment variables very carefully. Don't use semicolon or comma at the end of the line. Also you don't have to put single or double quotes to wrap up your values(if you add it will work but this is not the right way of declaring your `.env` variables). So change your `.env` file in this way:

```sh
REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/api/
```

Finally restart your dev server.

For more information, [read this docs out](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of environment variables living in the .env file, you ought to add the following code to your project's entry file, it is often `App.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
```

Comment: Actually, no need to declare `axios`'s default baseURL. As per as [react's official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) Custom Environment Variables are available from `react-scripts@0.2.3` or higher. So declaring the variable in the  `.env` in a wrong format did the thing.